# Nodeos remembers the old public key

Tags: nodeos, testnet

I am following the instructions here:
[Local Multi-Node Testnet](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/usage/development-environment/local-multi-node-testnet)

Second time.

When I try to start the second node it prints out this error message:

> "Not producing block because I don't have the private key for
> EOS7Qf9KDFDqRUms1aCcocWXsxyoYy7X1vW6qjDTVYMJZ2sfj22DE"

When I look at my records I see that "EOS7Qf9KDFDqR..." is the public key from my first attempt to follow these instructions

Between the first and second attempts I deleted folders

```
~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/data
```

and

```
/home/aleksey/eosio-wallet
```

The system is Ubuntu 18.04

Where does that nodeos takes that public key then ?

Comment: not sure on Ubuntu but on OSX you'll find those at `~/eosio-wallet`

Comment: At Ubuntu it is /home/aleksey/eosio-wallet, I delete it every time I try to make the new net

Comment: I gave it that old pair of keys, now the second nodeos works and sometimes says "error 2019-05-30T10:16:06.396 thread-0  net_plugin.cpp:1108           operator()           ] sent a go away message: chain is forked, closing connection to 127.0.0.1:9876

Answer (score 1):

Eos keeps some "mongoc" files in the third location, for example /dev/shm/mongoc-29146

About a week ago nodeos crashed and one such file was left there.

I deleted it and nodeos now does not show that old public key and error message about it.